# Proof of Helly's Lemma complex version from the real version

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I have proved this version of Helly's Lemma.

> Given a real normed space $X$, $n \in \mathbb N$, $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n \in X^*$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then the following are equivalent: 
>  **i)** For
> all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1$ and $\vert \varphi_i(x) - a_i \vert < \varepsilon$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$. 
>  **ii)** For all $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb R$, we have $\displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \, b_i \right\vert \leq \left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \,\varphi_i\right\Vert.$

I want to prove the complex version of this lemma using the version I already proved, i.e. I want to prove that

> Given a complex normed space $X$, $n \in \mathbb N$, $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n \in X^*$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$, then the following are equivalent: 
>  **i)** For
> all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in X$ such that $\Vert x \Vert \leq 1$ and $\vert \varphi_i(x) - a_i \vert < \varepsilon$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$. 
>  **ii)** For all $b_1, \ldots, b_n \in \mathbb C$, we have $\displaystyle\left\vert \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \, b_i \right\vert \leq \left\Vert \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \,\varphi_i\right\Vert.$

In the implication **i)** $\Rightarrow$ **ii)**, it does not matter in which field we work. But when I proved **ii)** $\Rightarrow$ **i)** in the real case, I used the following version of the Hahn-Banach theorem:

> Let $X$ be a real normed space. If $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint convex sets, $A$ is closed and $B$ is compact, then there exist $\varphi \in X^*$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$ such that $\varphi(x) < \alpha < \beta < \varphi(y)$  for all $x \in A$ and  $y \in B.$

So I can't see how to use this theorem to prove the complex version of Helly's theorem. Is there a way to prove the complex version from the real one?

Comment: Did you try to apply the real version to the functionals $\phi_i = \Re \varphi_i$, $\varphi_{i+n} = \Im \varphi_i$ and the numbers $\alpha_i = \Re a_i$, $\alpha_{i+n} = \Im a_i$?

Comment: @gerw Yes and I tried to prove **ii)** in the real version with $\beta_i = \Re b_i$ and $\beta_{i+n} = \Im b_i$, but I got stuck.